# How to cluster a set of 3D points on a grid?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, cluster-analysis

I have a set of 3D points on a grid and I would like to know how to cluster them such that every point in a given cluster is at most a certain distance (Euclidean distance) from at least one point in that cluster.

For example, suppose there are 5 points: `{A, B, C, D, E}`. If point `A` is at most 1.414 units from `B`, then they belong in the same cluster, and if point `C` is at most 1.414 units from `A` or `B`, then it also belongs to that cluster. If, on the other hand, `D` is more than 1.414 units from either `A`, `B`, or `C`, then it doesn't belong in that cluster and so on.

Input data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FWSIfsGwSyIUxlGDyC7Ya7mTkpv1jsge/view?usp=sharing).
Output that I require is size of each cluster, center (centroid) of each cluster and what points are in a particular cluster.

While this is not strictly a clustering problem, I have tried k-means, DBSCAN clustering methods but couldn't get optimal results.
Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [hierarchical clustering](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy) gives you a higher degree of control, although it may be slower than other methods for large datasets.

However, your clustering rules don't seem compatible with each other:

> 1. If point A is at most 1.414 units from B, then they belong in the same cluster and if point C is at most 1.414 units from B or C then it also belongs to that cluster.
> 2. If on the other hand, D is more than 1.414 units from either A, B, or C, then it doesn't belong in that cluster and so on.

For example, in 1D, points `[1,2,3]` belong to the same cluster, according to rule 1. And points `[2,3,4]` would also be on the same cluster.

However, according to rule 2, points `[1,2,3,4]` won't be part of the same cluster, while points 2 and 3 belong to clusters `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,4]`.

If you rephrase the second rule as

> 2. If on the other hand, D is more than 1.414 units from **all** A, B, or C, then it doesn't belong in that cluster and so on.

Then you are specifying what's known as the [single linkage method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering), that you can use like this:

```
>>> X = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0],
         [0, 4], [0, 3], [1, 4],
         [4, 0], [3, 0], [4, 1],
         [4, 4], [3, 4], [4, 3]]
>>> from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster, single
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
>>> y = pdist(X)
>>> Z = single(y)
>>> fcluster(Z, 1.414, criterion='distance')
[3 3 3 4 4 4 2 2 2 1 1 1]
```

Meaning that points `[0,1,2]` form cluster 3, points `[3,4,5]` form cluster 4 and so on.